# SWIFT: swipe table cell to change it's color

Tags: swift, uitableview, row, cell

I am new to Swift (and to coding), so please bear with me.  On my table, I have set up the cells so that when I swipe right, I see two options: "done" and "delete."  When I click on "delete," the cell row is removed.  When I click on "done," I want the cell row to change color.  I don't know how I got to this point, but when I click on "done," the whole table changes color *except* for the cell row.  I tried to use my reusable identifier for the cell prototype, which I set as "cell," but that didn't work out because I'm not sure on how to declare the "cell" without it interfering with my CellForRowAt function.

Here is my code:

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
        self.habits.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        print(self.habits)
    }
    let done = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath) in
        // save item at indexPath
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        print("Done")
    }

    done.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    return [delete, done]
}
```

I don't think I can declare "cell" because of this previous block of code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Dequeue Resuable Cell

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    let Habit = habits[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = Habit.mainGoal
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = Habit.microGoal

    return cell
```

Again, I am new to coding.  I already tried looking up this question and not quite sure if I am not wording it correctly, but I can't find the answer.  My backup idea is to strikethrough the labels in the cell, but from what I gathered, that is more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheave this by doing

```
 let done = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath) in
            // save item at indexPath
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            print("Done")
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  If I wanted it to reset every day, would that be a whole other thing? Or could I include it somewhere in this function?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the possible way to achieve your requirement.

https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit

Comment: This is not the OP question